# Refusing job offer after visa sponsorship

Tags: job-offer, hiring-process, human-resources, ethics, job-change

I recently landed a job in the UK about 5 months ago from a multinational company. They offered to sponsor my visa and arranged for the application process. However, in these months, I had some really unfortunate change of personal circumstances and relocating to UK and this particular job opportunity sounds very unpalatable to me at the moment.

I recently received the visa and its time to plan the travel. I understand it is unprofessional and highly inconvenient, but is it possible to refuse a job offer after they have sponsored a visa? What could be the possible fallout? Please help.

Comment: Did you sign any contract when accepting the job?

Comment: @DarkCygnus Yes, I believe I did :(

Comment: @Audrey you should check the contract that you've signed to see if there are any penalty clauses in it.

Answer (score 6):

The fallout would be that you would probably never get another opportunity with that company again.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few possible consequences that you should consider:

- It may invalidate your visa, consult with an immigration lawyer
- You'll almost certainly not have another opportunity with that company, or any subsidiary that shares an HR department with them
- Depending on the size of the company, you might also find that other companies will pass. Although strictly illegal in many jurisdictions to say anything about a prospective candidate or former employee other than confirming that they worked for you and the dates, there are *many* ways that information gets passed around.

> I had some really unfortunate change of personal circumstances and relocating to UK and this particular job opportunity sounds very unpalatable to me at the moment.

Depending on what these circumstances are, they may or may not be understanding. It's definitely challenging to understand with low amounts of detail. You might be able to defer the start date and/or entry to the firm. I hope your issues get resolved and you are able to pursue your next challenge.

Comment: Thanks for the response, much appreciated. I understand this visa would become invalid, I do not wish to enter UK at the moment. But would that have any effect on future visa applications?

Comment: It's unlikely to affect visa applications to the UK in the future. However, you should be prepared to answer questions during the visa application process as to why you were granted a visa and never used it. If a different company handles the whole process for you, they might be curious as well. It's unlikely they would terminate the process, but again, be prepared to answer questions.

Comment: This will definitely invalidate the visa.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer

Answer (score 0):

It's very possible your visa would become invalid and you would not be able to enter the country (or would be required to leave it).

You should discuss this matter with an immigration agent.

Comment: Thanks. I understand this visa would be invalidated, but does this have any impact on future visa applications with the same country (UK) ? Would you happen to know?

Comment: I have no idea. You should follow whatever procedure you have been told. If your are proactive in updating immigration, that will probably lead to better outcomes.